# How do I calculate a confidence interval with a description that on average one group is less than another?

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm having a lot of trouble understanding this.

If I have a 95% confidence interval (alpha = 0.05) how do I compute that one group gets fewer colds than the other, when I have the following information:

Group 1: Took medicine, 10 participants, so has 10 values representing number of colds that occurred in a year, for example:

0 1 2 8 0 2 3 6 2 4

Group 2: Didn't take medicine
7 3 8 9 3 11 9 8 2 7

All the information I'm given is that it is a normally distributed population with random samples and equal variance, and that *the group with medicine had fewer colds* how do I use this to calculate the confidence interval?

In the previous question, I got the answer rather quickly, because it just asked to calculate the confidence interval for the difference in means between the two groups, but this one introduces one having fewer colds. How do I deal with that?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that in this case you know that the group that took medicine showed improvements and so you know that the average $\bar x_{1}$ of Group1 is smaller than the average $\bar x_{2}$ of Group2. So you should use a one sided test to test for $\bar x_{2}-\bar x_{1}>0$. I hope this is what you are looking for.